# How can I go to previous Google doodles? I want to try solve the Alan Turing doodle

Tags: google-doodle

I found this link:

http://www.google.com/doodles/finder/2012/All%20doodles

It does not however let you interact with the interactive doodles, like the [Alan Turning code solver](http://www.google.com/doodles/alan-turings-100th-birthday).

I want to be able to interact with the doodle and try solving it again. I would also like to be able to go to any of the previous Google doodles. If anybody has links to previous Google doodle or knows how to activate them, like the [google search for zerg rush](https://www.google.co.za/webhp?q=zerg+rush).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the interactive doodles can be found by [searching the repository](http://www.google.com/doodles/search?query=interactive&sort=metatags-run_date). However, some of them are working only from Chrome, and the Turing doodle is one of them.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Weird, the PAC-MAN Doodle is still interactive here:
http://www.google.com/doodles/30th-anniversary-of-pac-man

If the Doodle is still available interactively I'm sure it would've been available through the page you suggested, so I think Google decided not to host that Doodle in it's full beauty, sadly.